# Using BotFramework Composer with other NLU Engines

Tags: botframework, dialogflow-es

The bot we have created uses DialogFlow as NLU Engine and uses MS BotFramework core as a dialog manager that creates dialogs as steps.

The preview version of [Bot Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer) looks powerful and intuitive way to create the Dialogs and manage them. But none of the documentation or Ignite Videos give a clear view whether it can be used for other NLU's(for obvious reasons, they wanted to promote LUIS).

So, curious to know if some integrated the composed with other NLU's apart from LUIS. If so, what are the caveats.

Comment: did you solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though LUIS provides a builtin way of managing intents in Bot Framework Composer, you can still access external API's like any NLU endpoints you want to use by incorporating an HTTP step into your dialog.

[image: HTTP step]

Comment: Cool. Will try accessing the DialogFlow via this and will post the results.